# Java async posting data structure

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, data-structures

I have an Android app that currently opens up an webview-activity. As it does so, it starts an async call to download some data at the same time as it loads a webpage in the webview.

As soon as both webpage and data are ready I want to send the data to the webview.

I was looking for a good data structure to do this. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
private String data;
private AtomicBoolean bothReady = new AtomicBoolean(false);


public void dataDownloaded(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    sendDataIfReady();
}

public void pageLoaded() {
    sendDataIfReady();
}

private void sendDataIfReady() {
    if (bothReady.getAndSet(true)) {
        sendData(this.data);
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version but that's the gist of it. It feels like a clunky way to do it, I was wondering if there was a good data structure in Java that sort of queues up data that's ready and then sends it when the page is ready, regardless of which finishes first (and obviously handles race conditions etc).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For async-requests I recomment you to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(20);
```

Then you can define AsyncNotice class:

```
class AsyncNotice implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some needed work
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
scheduler.schedule(new AsyncNotice(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or

```
scheduler.execute(new AsyncNotice());
```

This returns [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html), so you can even cancel it in the future.